# How to replace a string that does NOT match IP address with a dummy IP address?

Tags: text-processing, ip-address

I have a file with a list of IP addresses, but some of the strings are not IP addresses and I want to replace such strings with a dummy IP address.

I am using this `grep` to search for IP; but don't know how to replace what does not match with a dummy IP address. I believe this can be done with `sed`.
I tried few things but none of them worked.

```
cat file.txt | grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

I have this `sed` to match IP addresses in the file, but I have no idea how to replace non IP addresses with a dummy IP.

```
sed -rn '/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/p' file.txt
```

Input:

```
192.168.10.20
00 03
10.28.214.5
192.168.10.40
BF
192.168.10.50
```

Desired Output:

```
192.168.10.20
192.168.0.0
10.28.214.5
192.168.10.40
192.168.0.0
192.168.10.50
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer uses `awk` and addresses the fact that a valid IPv4 address is not simply 4 tuples of up to 3 digits, but also the constraint on digits being smaller than 256:

```
awk -v dummy="192.168.0.0" -F'.' 'NF!=4 {$0=dummy}
    NF==4 {for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {if ( !($i~/^[0-9]{1,3}$/) || $i>255) {$0=dummy;break}}} 1' input.txt
```

This will specify the dummy IP as variable `dummy`. It will then consider the `.` as field separator and check if

- there are exactly 4 fields, and
- if each field consists of only 1-3 digits, with the resulting number being smaller than 256

If any condition is not met, replace the line with the dummy IP. After processing, the line (including any modifications made) is printed.

Note that your proposed RegExp would not only accept byte fields larger than 255, but for lack of anchoring also lines where only a sub-string happens to match "4 numbers of 1-3 digits, separated by periods".

Answer (score 7):

Your regexp will match things which are **not** IPv4 dotted-quad addresses but look similar to them (e.g. `256.256.256.256` - looks a lot like an IPv4 address, but isn't).

To match only **valid** IPv4 addresses, you need to use a regex like:

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

or (without the perlish `?:` non-capturing group modifiers):

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

and this needs to be properly anchored, e.g. with `^` and `$`, `\b` on both ends, or `\<` and `\>`.

See: [Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9780596802837/ch07s16.html) by Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan, published by O'Reilly Media, Inc.

e.g.

```
$ sed -E '/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/!s/.*/192.168.0.0/' file.txt 
192.168.10.20
192.168.0.0
10.28.214.5
192.168.10.40
192.168.0.0
192.168.10.50
```

```
$ perl -p -e 's/.*/192.168.0.0/ unless m/^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/' file.txt 
192.168.10.20
192.168.0.0
10.28.214.5
192.168.10.40
192.168.0.0
192.168.10.50
```

Both of these change the entire input line to 192.168.0.0 unless the line matches a valid IPv4 address.

Personally, I would use perl's [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common) module, which is a large collection of regexes for common pattern-matching tasks, conveniently available in a hash called`%RE`.

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common -p -e 's/.*/192.168.0.0/ unless m/^$RE{net}{IPv4}$/' file.txt 
192.168.10.20
192.168.0.0
10.28.214.5
192.168.10.40
192.168.0.0
192.168.10.50
```

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE: others have pointed out that your chosen regular expression for an IPv4 address is flawed. I will not attempt to address that here since it is covered well elsewhere.**

You can use sed's **c**hange command on lines that do not (`!`) match your RE, ex.

```
$ sed -r '/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/!c\
192.168.0.0
' file.txt
192.168.10.20
192.168.0.0
10.28.214.5
192.168.10.40
192.168.0.0
192.168.10.50
```

With GNU sed, you can simplify to

```
sed -r '/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/!c192.168.0.0' file.txt
```

Comment: OMG THANKS A LOT.. I was so close; but guys are great!

Comment: `-r` is GNU specific anyway. See `-E` for the (soon-to-be) standard equivalent.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would not only accept strings where the individual fields are larger than 255, but also strings like `123.4532.432.2.4` where only the trailing `532.432.2.4` actually "matches" (i.e. in general also lines where only a sub-string contains four 1-to-3-digit numbers separated by periods).

Comment: @AdminBee IMHO the focus of the question is the mechanism for text replacement - I will leave critique of the OP's regex to others

Comment: The same approach can be implemented with an `s` command instead of a `c` command.  I tend to prefer `s` over `c` for single-line replacements because it does not require you to embed backslashes and newlines in the command.

Comment: Thanks to all. I know that my sed its not strictly and an ip like this 192.304.260.3 will accept it but Im taking the file from real IP Addresses taken diectly from switches. But thanks for all those script lines that validates Ip. It maybe useful in the future. I see all different script lines here and keep trying to learn from all. Thanks. Reallyy

Answer (score 5):

```
sed '/^\([[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}$/!s/.*/192.168.0.0/' data
```

If the line is not a valid IPv4 address then replace the current line with : `192.168.0.0`.

I advise you to use another value for the dummy address instead of `192.168.0.0` but this is up to you and to youts needs.

Or the same but with `awk`:

```
awk '!/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/ {$0="192.168.0.0"}1' data
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -MNet::IP -ple '$_ = "192.168.0.0" unless new Net::IP($_)' data
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Perl`:

- define the regex of an octet which comprises one to three digits with the constraint that it be nonzero leading unless it's single digit.
- match  that the line comprises exactly 4 octets separated by dots.
- split the Line on dots and that all the tuples are less than 256.

```
dummy=192.168.0.0 \
perl -MList::Util=all -lpe '
  $octet //= qr/(?!0\d)\d{1,3}/;

  /^$octet(?:[.]$octet){3}$/ &&
   all { $_<256 } split /[.]/ or
     $_ = $ENV{dummy};
' file
```